# What's the difference between the rehash() and reserve() methods of the C++ unordered_map?

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++11, std, unordered-map

What's the difference between the `rehash()` and `reserve()` methods of the C++ `unordered_map`? Why are two different methods needed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference is in *purpose*, although both are doing something similar.

- `rehash` takes an existing map and rebuilds a *new* size of buckets, rehashing in the process and redistributing elements into the new buckets.
- `reserve` guarantees you that if you don't insert more than the reserved number of elements, there will be no rehashing (i.e. your iterators will remain valid).

Those are two somewhat different things, albeit related. `rehash` doesn't give you any guarantees, and `reserve` doesn't express the purpose of rehashing. Use `rehash` if you think your map is inefficient, and `reserve` if you're preparing for a lot of insertions.

As @Xeo points out, `reserve` is just a wrapper around `rehash`, though, taking into account the permissible load factor of the map.

Comment: `reserve` is specified in terms of `rehash(ceil(n / max_load_factor()))`

Comment: Note that the current gcc implementation will rehash if you insert exactly the reserved number (so you might want to reserve an extra one). The discussion at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71181 indicates that this behavior is not compliant with an updated version of the C++ standard (so it will probably be fixed in the future).

Answer (score 1):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/):

> rehash: A rehash is the reconstruction of the hash table: All the elements in the       > container are rearranged according to their hash value into the new set of buckets. This    > may alter the order of the elements within the container.
>
> reserve: Sets the number of buckets in the container (bucket_count) to the most appropriate > to contain at least n elements.

I understand from here that rehash tries to change number of buckets in hashtable in respect to given size of n. reserve changes number of buckets in hashtable to the most appropriate number in order to store at least n (given by user) elements. I hope i made my statement clear.